# my php notification count can't show correct result

Tags: php

In my notification of total activities count I created as described below, which can't show correct result as I want. Please see my code below with described And My **Question** at the bottom of my code.

Detail of my code made as:

1. I find out all of my follow and followers ids, (Into follow table).
2. Then with above ids, I find out all activities done by these ids, (Into update table).

   a. In my notification drop-down lest, If any activity I see once and hover it, my javascript code make it view= 1. Otherwise view= 0 is my default value.

   b. If view once, my code deduct total view from total count.
3. In my 1st query I used my id to find out all of my follow and followers, which also show my own activities also. So I make here another query to find out all of my activities to deduct it from total count.

That`s All; Here is my code:

```
global $dbh;
$myid = $session->id;

//1.
$q = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM follow WHERE friend_one='$myid' OR friend_two='$myid'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$f_id = $row['friend_one'];
$f2_id = $row['friend_two'];

//2.
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);
$g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM update WHERE `from_id`='".$f_id."' OR `to_id`='".$f_id."' OR `from_id`='".$f2_id."' OR `to_id`='".$f2_id."' AND `view` = '0' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
    $count1 = mysqli_num_rows($g);
        $id = $row['id'];

//2.b
$v = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM update WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '1' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($v);

//3.
$c = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM update WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `from_id`='".$myid."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $count3 = mysqli_num_rows($c);

// Total count
$count = ($count1 - $count2 - $count3);

echo '.$count.';
```

**Question**
On my above script //2.b cannot count all ids which already viewed? Its count only '1' always.

Comment: Please described me before down vote. Thank.

Answer (score 2):

You want to count all id's, but the query is explicitly limiting the result to a specific id: `id='".$id."'".`

Comment: Thank u sir but how to count all ids here please.

Comment: What happens when you remove the id part of the query?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding you I think, is that different from what you want to get?